# Jquery 23 Second Delay change div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I implemented my Cub3r like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.xml = "config.xml";
            flashvars.font = "font.swf";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.wmode = "transparent";
            attributes.id = "slider";
            swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
    </script>
```

And I wish to change the `cu3er.swf` to `a.swf` i have made after `23 seconds` using `jQuery`. How could I do this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("printmachine.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really jQuery specific, what you need is to use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// your code ...
swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", /*...*/);

setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('#cu3er-container').empty(); // in case swfobject doesn't clean the div before inserting, might not be needed
  swfobject.embedSWF("printmachine.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
}, 23000); // the number is in millisecond, so 23 * 1000 for 23 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript code

```
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.xml = "config.xml";
flashvars.font = "font.swf";
var attributes = {};
attributes.wmode = "transparent";
attributes.id = "slider";
swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);

setTimeout(function ()
{
   swfobject.embedSWF("a.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
}, 23000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the **.delay()** in jquery so you can launch the substitution after a defined amount of time
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `.delay()` is overkill here - really not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery 1.4+ onwards there is delay function try using that