# Loop A Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

Hi I have this code below which basically after 25 seconds of showing the first `.swf` the second `.swf` shows. Now I wish to go back to the first after 12 seconds. and then loop in the same way. 1st swf 2nd swf 1st swf ......

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.xml = "config.xml";
            flashvars.font = "font.swf";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.wmode = "transparent";
            attributes.id = "slider";
            swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);

setTimeout(function() {
  swfobject.embedSWF("printmachine.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400" , "0");
}, 25000);
</script>
```

How would I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The same way you changed it the first time! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151826/jquery-23-second-delay-change-div

Comment: @Tim: I assume its the creating the loop that he is having problems with. Nothing in this code will do looping and just writing an infinite number of setTimeout calls is probably not a practical solution...

Comment: @Chris - Point taken. He could have at-least tried to do it first.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, but looking at his code there was no sign of named functions so I assumed his javascript knowledge wasn't great and that he might not have done timeouts with non-anonymous functions which is kind of necessary here. Ah well, he knows now anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following splits the showing of the SWFs into two different functions. Each function calls the other via a timeout. So it will show SWF1 and line up the SWF2 method for 25s. When this runs it loads SWF2 and lines up the SWF1 function for 12 seconds. And then it will loop from there alternating each SWF.

You can probably refactor it but this basic idea should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSwf1(){
        swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
        setTimeout(showSwf2, 25000);
    }

    function showSwf2(){
        swfobject.embedSWF("printmachine.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400" , "0");
        setTimeout(showSwf1, 12000);
    }

    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.xml = "config.xml";
    flashvars.font = "font.swf";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.wmode = "transparent";
    attributes.id = "slider";
    showSwf1();
</script>
```

N.B. Code is untested so apologies for minor typos or anything. Works when processed in my head though. ;-)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You could use setTimeout() with a proper delay and callback method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function aaa() {
  var flashvars = {};
  flashvars.xml = "config.xml";
  flashvars.font = "font.swf";
  var attributes = {};
  attributes.wmode = "transparent";
  attributes.id = "slider";
  swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
  setTimeout(bbb, 25000);
}

function bbb() {
  swfobject.embedSWF("printmachine.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400" , "0");
  setTimeout(aaa, 12000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
  swfobject.embedSWF("cu3er.swf", "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes);
}, 37000);

Comment: Ah then i misunderstood you. However it's the same principe;

Comment: Try `setInterval()` with a flag to know which one to switch to

Answer (score 1):

Turn your embed swf actions into a function this will loop infinitely and allow you to add any other SWFs to the array if you want to extend it in the future:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var swfs = [{swf:"cu3er.swf",delay:25000, flashvars:{xml:"config.xml",font:"font.swf"},attributes:{wmode:"transparent",id:"slider"}}, 
                {swf:"printmachine.swf",delay:12000,flashvars:{},attributes:{}}];
    loadSWF(0);        

    function loadSWF(ind){
        if(ind >= swfs.length)ind = 0;
        swfobject.embedSWF(swfs[ind].swf, "cu3er-container", "960", "400", "9", "expressInstall.swf", swfs[ind].flashvars, swfs[ind].attributes);
        setTimeout("loadSwf("+(ind+1)+")", swfs[ind].delay);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I did think about something more like that but the smbedSWF calls have different parameters passed (the first has three extra parameters) so I figured it was easier to just deal with the specific case here. :)

Comment: Your right Chris, I just updated to take the different params into account.

Comment: the "expressInstall.swf" is only in the first one too. ;-)

Comment: "expressInstall.swf" should only be invoked the first time it is invoked on a page. The installer package is required if you would like to pass in any additional variables, better to be safe than sorry. :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't really following the flash parts, just the javascript. Sounds like you know more than I do and probably have now provided a better answer than I did (certainly better if it needs to be expanded). :)